# How to Set Up a List of Clickable Images with GridView

Tags: android, gridview

How to Set Up a List of Clickable Images with GridView?

This work is inspired from this tutorial https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/748050-how-to-set-up-a-list-of-clickable-images-in-android-app-development-with-gridview

Why I have this error in my GridView?

```
length cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

My code follow:

```
        final String[] myPics = new String[] { R.drawable.file1, R.drawable.file2, 
                                               R.drawable.file3, R.drawable.file4 };

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, myPics));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                         i.setData(Uri.parse(myPics.getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
                         startActivity(i);          

            }
        });



private ImageWithUrl[] imageIds = {
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file1, "http://example.com/link1.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file2, "http://example.com/link2.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file3, "http://example.com/link3.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file4, "http://example.com/link4.html") };

public ImageWithUrl getItem(int position) {
    return imageIds[position];
}

protected class ImageWithUrl extends Object {
    private int imageId;
    private String imageUrlString;

    ImageWithUrl(int id, String url) {
        imageId = id;
        imageUrlString = url;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

public String getImageUrlString() {
    return imageUrlString;
}
}
```

**EDIT**

CustomAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            String mobile = mobileValues[position];

            if (mobile.contains("23/03/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file1);
            } else if (mobile.contains("09/03/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file2);
            } else if (mobile.contains("25/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file3);
            } else if (mobile.contains("16/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file4);
            } else if (mobile.contains("13/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file5);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file6);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

CustomAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            String mobile = mobileValues[position];

            if (mobile.contains("23/03/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file1);
            } else if (mobile.contains("09/03/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file2);
            } else if (mobile.contains("25/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file3);
            } else if (mobile.contains("16/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file4);
            } else if (mobile.contains("13/02/2014")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file5);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.file6);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        if (mobileValues != null && mobileValues.length > position) {
            return mobileValues[position];
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

        private ImageWithUrl[] imageIds = {
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file1, "http://example.com/link1.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file2, "http://example.com/link2.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file3, "http://example.com/link3.html"),
        new ImageWithUrl(R.drawable.file4, "http://example.com/link4.html") };

    protected class ImageWithUrl extends Object {
        private int imageId;
        private String imageUrlString;

        ImageWithUrl(int id, String url) {
            imageId = id;
            imageUrlString = url;
        }

        public int getImageId() {
            return imageId;
        }

        public String getImageUrlString() {
            return imageUrlString;
        }
    }
}
```

Activity class

```
final String[] myPics = new String[] { R.drawable.file1, R.drawable.file2, 
                                       R.drawable.file3, R.drawable.file4 };

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    final CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myPics);
    gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
            startActivity(i);          

            }
        });
```

Comment: This error occurred when ? can you post the code of your CustomAdapter ?

Comment: @Andros : thank you in edit first question I have posted CustomAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error seems to be in your `onItemClick` method.

You are using a getItem in this line :

```
i.setData(Uri.parse(myPics.getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
```

But `myPics` is a `String[]` if you want the item at position "position" in your myPics array, you need to retrieve it like that : myPics[position].

However want you want to do is to get the object at position in your adapter, so what you have to do is :

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myPics)
gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(myAdapter.getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
    startActivity(i);          

    }
});
```

And in your adapter, implement the getItem method :

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    if (mobileValues != null && mobileValues.length > position) {
        return mobileValues[position];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Sorry I misread the error :

in your case I think if you just do :

```
i.setData(Uri.parse(getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
```

It should be ok.

Comment: thanks but now I've this error `The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`

Comment: Ok, it's normal. My bad. In order to do something clean, you have to use my 1st solution, so implement the getItem method in your custom Adapter. (you can use your ImageWithUrl object to populate the adapter if you want).

Comment: please look my last edit in first question, I have posted the CustomAdapter and Activity classes java... I have error `The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} `

Comment: Replace Uri.parse(getItem(position).getImageUrlString()) by Uri.parse(myAdapter.getItem(position))

Comment: Thank you: I have replaced the code and now the error is `The method getImageUrlString() is undefined for the type String`

Comment: just remove getImageUrlString()

Comment: Okay, removed in code `getImageUrlString()`. I need when image in GV is clicked redirect to link provided on CustomAdapter class in `private ImageWithUrl[] imageIds`. Now when click on a image in GV I have the crash of application ...

Comment: Don't use String[] in your Adapter, and use your object ImageWithUrl